# Is it possible to detect specific UVB wavelength ranges using just a UVM-30A UV sensor or similar

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

Is it possible to detect specific UVB wavelength ranges using just a UVM-30A UV sensor or similar.

The sensor in consideration is [GUVA-S12SD](http://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/TOY0044/guva-s12sd.pdf).

Seems to indicate that it generates a specific current level when sensing a specific wavelength, but because its sensing a range of wavelengths I guess you get the summation?

Is it possible to use any techniques to perform a UV spectral analysis on the output so as to detect the presence of a specific wavelength band.

It also important to determine relative intensity over time for the band. Is this anyway possible?

I'm not an engineer, but I can do any programming necessary.

Can anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

Your spec sheet lists the following:

> Spectral Detection Range λ 10% of R 240 - 370 nm

That means: over the range 240 to 370 nm, the responsivity is at least 10% of the peak responsivity (R).  So look at the spec for R:

> Responsivity R λ = 300 nm, UR = 0 V - 0.14 - A/W

The responsivity at other wavelengths is shown to be quite small in the following graph.   A brief ride on the InfoSuperHighway suggests GaN detectors in general have that sort of shortwave (and longwave) limit.

As to your other questions: rather obviously you cannot determine what the input wavelength is from the electrical output, as there is only one output.  You would need a set of narrowbandpass UV filters to measure a restricted band with this device.